# PC to Android File Transfer through Sockets

Tags: android, client-server

How to transfer a file(unknown extension ie maybe a pdf/word/jpeg) from PC to Android Phone using Socket Programming. The Android Phone should be able to detect the type of file transfer and should be able to open it thereafter. Also the file should go into a specific folder named after app name in External storage.

I have tried following solution. However in this case, when I select the file to be transferred, the file transferred at Android side is of arbitrary size and not of the same size as of file selected, it is of some random size. Also the file transferred cannot be opened as it does not have a fixed extension.

Any help would be appreciated.

Android code(To receive file)

```
package minor.subham.com.pccontrol;

import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;




public class getFile extends ActionBarActivity {

    ImageView getFile;
    public final static int SOCKET_PORT = Constants.SERVER_PORT;      // you may change this
    public final static String SERVER = Constants.SERVER_IP;  // localhost

    public final static int FILE_SIZE = 6022386; // file size temporary hard coded
    // should bigger than the file to be downloaded



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_get_file);

        getFile = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.getFile);





        getFile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Thread thread = new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        while(true) {


                            int bytesRead;
                            int current = 0;
                            FileOutputStream fos = null;
                            BufferedOutputStream bos = null;
                            Socket sock = null;
                            final File file;
                            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "PcControl");

                            try {
                                sock = new Socket(SERVER, SOCKET_PORT);
                                System.out.println("Connecting...");

                                // receive file
                                byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [FILE_SIZE];
                                InputStream is = sock.getInputStream();
                               // fos = new FileOutputStream(FILE_TO_RECEIVED);
                                try {

                                    fos = new FileOutputStream(file);

                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }



                                bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
                                bytesRead = is.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
                                current = bytesRead;

                                do {
                                    bytesRead =
                                            is.read(mybytearray, current, (mybytearray.length-current));
                                    if(bytesRead >= 0) current += bytesRead;
                                } while(bytesRead > -1);

                                bos.write(mybytearray, 0 , current);
                                bos.flush();
                                fos.write(mybytearray);
                                fos.close();
                                System.out.println("File "
                                        + " downloaded (" + current + " bytes read)");
                            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            } finally {
                                if (fos != null) try {
                                    fos.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                if (bos != null) try {
                                    bos.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                if (sock != null) try {
                                    sock.close();
                                } catch (IOException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }


                        }
                    }
                };

                thread.start();


            }
        });

    }







 }
```

And Her is the Java Code to send file. Suppose I want to send file temp.jpg

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class send {

  public final static int SOCKET_PORT = 8991;  // you may change this
  public final static String FILE_TO_SEND = "temp.jpg";  // you may change this

  public static void main (String [] args ) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    BufferedInputStream bis = null;
    OutputStream os = null;
    ServerSocket servsock = null;
    Socket sock = null;
    try {
      servsock = new ServerSocket(SOCKET_PORT);
     // while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting...");
        try {
          sock = servsock.accept();
          System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);

      // send file
      File myFile = new File (FILE_TO_SEND);
      byte [] mybytearray  = new byte [(int)myFile.length()];
      fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
      bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      bis.read(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      os = sock.getOutputStream();
      System.out.println("Sending " + FILE_TO_SEND + "(" + mybytearray.length + " bytes)");
      os.write(mybytearray,0,mybytearray.length);
      os.flush();
      System.out.println("Done.");
    }
    finally {
      if (bis != null) bis.close();
      if (os != null) os.close();
      if (sock!=null) sock.close();
    }
 // }
}
finally {
  if (servsock != null) servsock.close();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well why can't the file be opened? Explain in detail please.

Comment: Well because the file transferred has no fixed extension. The file created in Android Phone is of arbitrary size. For eg. if temp.jpg is of 300kb then the file output in phone is of 7 Mb.

Comment: It does not have to have a fixed extension. As long as it has an extension. So unclear what you mean. And if the resulting file is different in length than the original file then that is your first problem! Why didn't you mention that in your post to begin with? Please edit your post and tell what goes wrong first.

Comment: `Please Help!!!`. Don't do such things. You better remove that.

Comment: `the file transferred is of arbitrary size`. Of course your code should be able to transfer files of arbitrary size. If you mean something different then please reword.

Comment: Sorry for causing ambiguity. Let me re explain. After File transfer starts, I receive a new file in Android phone that has name 'Pccontrol' as expected. However it does not have any extension. Moreover the file transferred is not of same size as selected in the first place. It is of some random size. What i want to do is select any file from Pc and send it to Android Phone and once I open the File on Android, it should be able to open that,

Comment: You should explain all at start of your post. Not afterwards in a comment. Make a decent post!